# I want the current "i" that's being tested in an if/then statement

Tags: c#

**Problem**

As a person who is more familiar with Javascript than C#, I seek a way to accomplish what has to be a simple task in C#, but am not seeing it straightaway.

**Notes**
Ideally, this would not use LINQ or any other 'advanced' form of code.  There simply must be a basic way to do this because the code knows what it is I want.

The intent is to be able to test every value in the List regardless of the variations of input data.  Thus why I don't want to have to do explicit testing if I can avoid it.

And myList is a List string, sorry.

I've checked a number of variations in Intellisense and none of them are doing what it appears to be doing, and I've isolated down to the if/then.  I don't mind using something other than if/then as long as it does what it needs to - and as long as it's not 'advanced' code.

Here's an example of the snippet:

```
int instance;

if (myList.Contains("SomeText"))
{
  instance = myList.SelectedIndex;
}
```

So basically, in this pseudo code, SelectedIndex says, "okay, there are 12 in the list and we found your text at zero-based position 9, so 'instance' should return an int of 9".  That's what I want.

But I don't see an equivalent to SelectedIndex.  There's IndexOf, but then I'm repeating the same test data as was in the if/then.  I can do that, but that feels like an inefficient way to do what I want - test once, act once.

Comment: `var foundIndex = myList.IndexOf("SomeText");` Then do whatever with `foundIndex`. If it's greater than -1, the string was found. If `foundIndex == -1`, the string wasn't found. I've never heard of that `SelectedIndex` feature in JS; is it new?

Comment: I agree with @EdPlunkett. `IndexOf` will return the zero based index you're looking for. If the list doesn't contain the text, then the method will return `-1`. So you can check by doing something like: `if ( x != -1) { instance = x; }`

Comment: But what is the type of `myList`? Is it `List<String>` or something else entirely? Please provide basic, important information like that in your questions.

Comment: What type of object is 'myList'? Is it in fact a System.Collections.Generic.List<string> or is it some other type of object?

Comment: I like @Ed-Plunkett's comment.  It's not letting me vote up, but it's an intriguing way to tackle it.

Comment: So @EdPlunkett, if you can submit yours as an answer vs. a comment (I think) I'll accept.  It appears to be working perfectly.  Thank you.  And in basic JS, SelectedIndex is/was (I think it's been deprecated long since) a way to get the value that a user picked from a dropdown where the values were coming from the script itself.  So you can declare an index/value pair, tell an HTML object to read that into UI, then query what the user picked.  Old school, but I knew there had to be a C# rough equivalent.

Comment: Array.indexOf() has been in JS for a long, long, long time.

Comment: Sure - in JS. I'm referring to good old fashioned HTML-used JavaScript for DOM manipulation.  And a simple SELECT isn't seen by the DOM as an array.  It's seen as an element that happens to have indexes.